# How can i get all URL's of a google chrome window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

im currently developing an extension, but im kind of lost by the moment.
Basically, what i want it to do, its kind of what "OneTab" extension does.

So my first question is, after adding the listener to the extension button, and executing the function, i want to get all the url's of the current window, and store them in an array and the show them in the html file.

So im using this:

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab) {
    var tablink = tab.url;
    console.log(tablink);
  });
```

but its not working and im not sure how it will check all the tabs one by one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to [so].  So that it's easier to answer your question and also help you improve your understanding, please provide us with some more information.  What doesn't work with it?  What are you doing this?  If you could provide this information, that would be great.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chrome.tabs.getSelected() will only get you the current tab.

In order to get the list of all the tabs in the current window, you need to use the chrome.windows API. This API will return an object of the current window which will have the list of tab objects.

Here is the sample code:

```
chrome.windows.getCurrent({"populate":true}, function(currentWindow) {
   var tabURLs = [];
   var tabs = currentWindow.tabs;
   for (var i=0; i<tabs.length; i++) {
       tabURLs.push(tabs[i].url);
   }
   console.log(tabURLs);
});
```

For details check:

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#method-getCurrent